# What does a subscript F represent?

Tags: matrices, notation, normed-spaces

On [page 11 of the slide](http://www.cs.toronto.edu/~bonner/courses/2019f/csc411/lectures/07_multiclass.pdf),

Sum-of-least-square loss:

$$
\ell\left(\mathbf{\tilde W}\right)
 = \sum_{n=1}^N \left\| \mathbf{\tilde W}^T\mathbf{\tilde x^{(n)}}
                       -\mathbf{t}^{(n})
                \right\|^2
 = \left\|\mathbf{\tilde X\tilde W-T}\right\|^2_F
$$

- the $n$-th row of $\mathbf{\tilde X}$ is $\left[\mathbf{\tilde x}^{(n)}\right]^T$
- the $n$-th row of $\mathbf{T}$ is $\left[\mathbf{t}^{(n)}\right]^T$

I don't get what the subscript $F$ means in the equation.

I don't even know what tags I should put. Any modification would be appreciated!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The subscript $F$ denotes the [Frobenius norm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_norm#Frobenius_norm): if $A=[a_{ij}]$ in $n\times m$ matrix then
$$\|A\|_F=\sqrt{\text{trace}(A^*A)}=\sqrt{\sum_{i=1}^n\sum_{j=1}^m|a_{ij}|^2}.$$