# Does Frobenius Norm affect matrix transpose?

Tags: matrices, transpose, frobenius-method

On [page 11 of the slide](http://www.cs.toronto.edu/~bonner/courses/2019f/csc411/lectures/07_multiclass.pdf),

Sum-of-least-square loss:

$$
\ell\left(\mathbf{\tilde W}\right)
 = \sum_{n=1}^N \left\| \mathbf{\tilde W}^T\mathbf{\tilde x^{(n)}}
                       -\mathbf{t}^{(n})
                \right\|^2
 = \left\|\mathbf{\tilde X\tilde W-T}\right\|^2_F
$$

- the $n$-th row of $\mathbf{\tilde X}$ is $\left[\mathbf{\tilde x}^{(n)}\right]^T$
- the $n$-th row of $\mathbf{T}$ is $\left[\mathbf{t}^{(n)}\right]^T$

The subscript $F$ denotes the [Frobenius Norm](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3555221/what-does-a-subscript-f-represent).

The expression above seems missed a step from the transpose.

This is what I would write:

$\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^N\|\mathbf{\tilde W}^T\mathbf{\tilde x^{(n)}}-\mathbf{t}^{(n})\|^2=\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^N\| [[\mathbf{\tilde W}^T\mathbf{\tilde x^{(n)}}-\mathbf{t}^{(n})]^T]^T\|^2=\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^N\| [[\mathbf{\tilde x}^{(n)}]^T\mathbf{\tilde W}-[\mathbf{t}^{(n)}]^T]^T\|^2=\|[\mathbf{\tilde X\tilde W-T}]^T\|^2_F$

We need 2 transposes to keep the expression unchanged, don't we?

The title may not describe my question well. Any modification would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that we have $$\|A\|_F^2=\|A^T\|_F^2$$

in general since both expression just sum up the square of each entry.